# Regex to apply two lookbehind criteria

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, lookbehind

I have a list of lowercase words on separate lines. I want to match all lines which contain the letter 'r' where it is NOT preceded by 'e' (er), NOR by 'fo' (for).

Here is a sample list:

```
fortnight
reject
forrest
fourteen
certain
forester
heretofore
example
```

Here are the words that I want to match:

```
reject
forrest
fourteen
```

Here are two regexes, each of which does half of what I want:

```
^(.*((?<!e)r).*)$
^(.*(r(?<!fo)r).*)$
```

The first matches all words except 'certain'; the second all words except 'fortnight', so the words I want are matched. However the words that contain both 'for' and 'er', with no other 'r' are also matched. Applying one regex after the other fails to eliminate the false positives.

How can I combine the two regexes with an AND condition, so that both are applied in one expression?

Comment: What language/regex engine you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple alternation as

```
^\w*(?<!e|fo)r\w*$
```

for example http:http://regex101.com/r/mW5qZ9/6

**What it does?**

`(?<!e|fo)` asserts that the regex is not presceded by `e` or `fo`

`r` matches character `r`

The regex would match

```
fourteen
reject
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess the asker wants the whole word to match, not just the letter `r`, should be easy enough to fix.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I edited the answer to include that as well. Thank you for pointing out :)

Comment: +1 since it works, but you should update it on regex101 too. Oh, and `(fo)` could be replaced with simply `fo`

Comment: This works, and it also matches "forrest", which I have now added to the list of words to test. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesNewton glad to hear it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

## RegEx:

This should work for most flavors of RegEx
`\w*(?<!e|fo)r+.*\w`